# how to connect api running on azure to connect to on-premises sql server database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have my api running on Azure and it is working perfect if it is connected to Azure SQL database.

I want this api to use my local database i.e on-premises database. I made my database to accept connection from remote and also enabled TCP/IP in wf.msc and also created an inbound rule for 1433. Is there anything i had to do to make this work? I tried to use the following connection string in azure :

ASP.Net core 2.0 web api written in C# hosted on azure and trying to access the sqlserver database on the Virtual Machine.

I tried as mentioned in the following to create hybrid connection but the status keeps saying 'Not Connected'

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections


Server=tcp:<mycomputername>,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userid;Password=pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Comment: As written, very broad with no specific details provided. We don't know what code you wrote (we don't even know the language used), or what errors you received. At this point, you'd only get guesses. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: I have edit my question. Bascially i have an asp.net core 2.0 webapi running on Azure. it works fine when i use Azure SQL Database connection string but i want to use OnPremise database which is running on VM. it is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

If your On-Prem SQL VM is behind firewall, you need to allow inbound from Azure. Usually you poke a hole in your On-Prem firewall and allow inbound from your `Azure` (source) to your On-Prem `SQL server` (Destination) on a  particular port.

Comment: thank you. i am totally new to this rules. is there any way to give me an example kind please? kind of steps to do to achieve this. I am sure my On-Prem SQL VM is behind firewall.

Comment: You are most probably not authorized to make such changes to your enterprise's firewall on your own. Talk to your IT department and they should know what to do.